# Computer Architecture Data Flow Graph

Tags: flow-charts

[image: Data Flow Graph Sample]

I am trying to draw a graph similar to this. I have no idea how to draw those arrow with angles and the "jump" when 2 path intersect. :(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Here are some examples: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/flowcharts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bumps can be made by arcs: `arc(90:-90:3pt)` gives a bump to the right, `arc(180:0:3pt)` gives an upright bump. The position *could* be computed, but this is a bit cumbersome for just two bumps, so they are positioned by hand in the drawing below.

The code below defines a command

```
\drawdh[options for \draw]{from-node}{to-node}{edge label}
```

that draws a diagonal-horizontal line from `from-node` to `to-node` and labels the diagonal line with `edge label`. Likewise, there is a command `\drawdv` for drawing a diagonal-vertical line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset
  {op/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=2.5em,inner sep=1pt,font=\small},
   cp/.style={op,node contents=copy},
   eq/.style={op,node contents={$=$}},
   eq0/.style={op,node contents={${=}0$}},
   br/.style={op,node contents={BR}},
   gr/.style={ground,right,point down},
   dec/.style={op,node contents={$-1$}},
   inc/.style={op,node contents={$+1$}},
   >=stealth
  }
\newcommand\drawdh[4][]% diagonal horizontal
  {\draw[#1]
     let \p1=(#2),\p2=(#3) in
     (#2) -- node[above,font=\scriptsize]{#4} 
     ({\x1+abs(\y2-\y1)*sign(\x2-\x1)},\y2) -- (#3);%
  }
\newcommand\drawdv[4][]% diagonal vertical
  {\draw[#1]
     let \p1=(#2),\p2=(#3) in
     (#2) -- node[above,font=\scriptsize]{#4} 
     (\x2,{\y1+abs(\x2-\x1)*sign(\y2-\y1)}) -- (#3);%
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,circuit ee IEC]
  % below n
  \node (n) {$n$};
  \node (c1) [cp,below=of n];
  \node (e1) [eq0,below right=of c1];
  \node (c2) [cp,below=of e1];
  \node (b1) [br,below left=of c1,yshift=-3cm];
  \node (d1) [dec,left=3cm of e1];
  \draw[->] (n) -- coordinate (nc1) (c1);
  \draw[->] (c1) -- (e1);
  \draw[->] (e1) -- (c2);
  \drawdv[->]{c1}{b1}{}
  \drawdh[->]{c2}{b1}{}
  \draw[->] (b1) -- node[above,font=\scriptsize]{T} ++( 0.8,-0.8) coordinate (b1T);
  \draw (b1T) -- +(0,-0.2) node[gr]{};
  \draw[->] (b1) --node[above,font=\scriptsize]{F} ++(-0.8,-0.8) -| (d1);
  \draw[->] (d1) |- (nc1);
  % below x
  \node[left=6.5cm of n] (x) {$x$};
  \node (c3) at (x|-c2) [cp];
  \node (b2) [br,below left=of c3,yshift=-1.5cm];
  \node (e2) [eq,below right=of c3];
  \draw[->] (x) -- coordinate[pos=0.8] (xc3) (c3);
  \drawdv[->]{c3}{b2}{}
  \draw[->] (c3)--(e2);
  \draw[->] (b2) -- node[above,font=\scriptsize]{T} ++( 0.8,-0.8) coordinate (b1T);
  \draw (b1T) -- +(0,-0.2) node[gr]{};
  \draw[->] (b2) --node[above,font=\scriptsize]{F} ++(-0.8,-0.8) -- ++(-0.5,0) |- (xc3);
  \draw[->] (d1) |- (nc1);
  \draw[->] (c2) |- (b2);
  % below v 
  \node[right=2.5cm of x,%
    label={[right,align=left,yshift=-6ex]$v_{n-1}$\\$v_{n-2}$\\$\vdots$\\$v_0$}] (v) {};
  \drawdv[<-]{e2}{v}{}
  % below 0
  \node[right=3.5cm of n] (0) {$0$};
  \node (b3) at (0|-b1) [br];
  \node (b4) [br,below right=4mm of b3,yshift=-1.5cm];
  \node (i1) [inc,below left=4mm of b4,yshift=-1cm];
  \draw[->] (0) -- coordinate[pos=0.8] (0b3) (b3);
  \drawdh[->]{c2}{b3}{}
  \draw[->] (b3) -- node[above,font=\scriptsize]{T} ++(-0.8,-0.8) -- ++(0,-5) node[below]{answer};
  \drawdv[->]{b3}{b4}{F}
  \drawdv[->]{b4}{i1}{T}
  \draw[->] (b4) -- node[above,font=\scriptsize]{F} ++( 0.8,-0.8) -- ++(0.5,0) coordinate (b4F);
  \draw[->] (i1) |- ($(b4F)+(0,-2)$) |- (0b3);
  \draw[->] (e2) -- ++(0,-1.4) arc(90:-90:3pt) |- ($(b4)+(-1.83,0)$) arc(180:0:3pt) -- (b4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```